# Remove the kernel on a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

How can I remove a kernel from Jupyter Notebook?

I have an R kernel on my Jupyter Notebook. Recently, the kernel always dies right after I open a new notebook.

Answer (score 514, accepted):

Run `jupyter kernelspec list` to get the paths of all your kernels. 
Then simply uninstall your unwanted-kernel

```
jupyter kernelspec uninstall unwanted-kernel
```

**Old answer** 
Delete the folder corresponding to the kernel you want to remove.

The docs has a list of the common paths for kernels to be stored in: http://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kernels.html#kernelspecs

Comment: Maybe obvious comment: You have to activate the virtualenv in which you installed jupyter before you can run the command.

Comment: `jupyter kernelspec remove <kernel_name>` now exists see my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/52606602/4413446

Comment: Yes, if the kernel is deleted manually then that is effectively the same as uninstalling it

Comment: What if this leaves some traces? When I install a kernel with the same name after this, the kernel does not work properly.

Answer (score 78):

`jupyter kernelspec remove` now exists, see [#7934](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7934).
So you can just.

```
# List all kernels and grap the name of the kernel you want to remove
jupyter kernelspec list
# Remove it
jupyter kernelspec remove <kernel_name>
```

That's it.

Comment: Yeah, `uninstall` is simply an alias of `remove` these days...

Comment: This is a more complete answer, the first command allows you to check all the venvs linked to the jupyter notebooks.

Comment: Thanks for the list command! Very helpful

Answer (score 75):

You can delete it in the terminal via:

```
jupyter kernelspec uninstall yourKernel
```

where `yourKernel` is the name of the kernel you want to delete.

Comment: `sudo` may not even be necessary. This is a much better answer than the accepted one.

Comment: I did it today without sudo. And definitely this is the cleanest way. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: The accepted answer was updated at some point with my content, so that the user can keep collecting upvotes... :D

Answer (score 27):

There are two ways which is what I found. Either go to the directory where kernels are residing and delete from there. Secondly, using this command below.

List all kernels and grab the name of the kernel you want to remove

```
 jupyter kernelspec list
```

to get the paths of all your kernels.

Then simply uninstall your unwanted-kernel

```
jupyter kernelspec remove kernel_name
```

Answer (score 15):

Just for completeness, you can get a list of kernels with `jupyter kernelspec list`, but I ran into a case where one of the kernels did not show up in this list. You can find all kernel names by opening a Jupyter notebook and selecting `Kernel -> Change kernel`. If you do not see everything in this list when you run `jupyter kernelspec list`, try looking in [common Jupyter folders](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-directories.html):

```sh
ls ~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels  # usually where local kernels go
ls /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels  # usually where system-wide kernels go
ls /usr/share/jupyter/kernels  # also where system-wide kernels can go
```

Also, you can delete a kernel with `jupyter kernelspec remove` or `jupyter kernelspec uninstall`. The latter is an alias for `remove`. From the in-line help text for the command:

```
uninstall
    Alias for remove
remove
    Remove one or more Jupyter kernelspecs by name.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this for `virtualenv`, the kernels in inactive environments might not be shown with `jupyter kernelspec list`, as suggested above. You can delete it from directory:

```
~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jupyter Notebook, run:

```
!echo y | jupyter kernelspec uninstall unwanted-kernel
```

In the [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) prompt, run:

```
jupyter kernelspec uninstall unwanted-kernel
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Example:**
To reverse the command `python -m ipykernel install --user --name tensorflow --display-name "Python 3.6 (tensorflow)"`, you need to uninstall the IPython kernel with the same name and display name.

You can do this by running the following command:

```
jupyter kernelspec uninstall tensorflow
```

This will remove the IPython kernel with the name "tensorflow" and the display name "Python 3.6 (tensorflow)" from your system.