# Delete 'Python Interactive' environment created by VSCode inside Jupyter?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, miniconda

I ran some jupyter notebook using VSCode. However, VSCode created some 'Python Interactive' environment which appears in my Jupyter Notebook. How do I remove them?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that's a bug in the python extension.

To delete them you can follow the directions here:
[remove kernel on jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635310/remove-kernel-on-jupyter-notebook)

They're just json files in a directory that Jupyter maintains. The VS Code python extension created them to get our kernel to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you still see these after deleting using `jupyter kernelspec uninstall unwanted-kernal`, you can clear these by uninstalling and then reinstalling your Jupyter extension in VSCode.

In VSCode, click the 'extensions' icon, then search 'Jupyter'. Uninstall it. Then install it.