# How to delete all the kernels in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, anaconda, kernel

I'm always using VSCode and some time ago I uninstalled anaconda. The problem is that when I use the Jupyter notebooks in VSCode if I don't remember of changing it, the kernel that it use as default is "opt/anaconda3/bin/python" that is gone. So, evertime I open VSCode I have to change the kernel.

I want to delete all the other kernels so VSCode hasn't the choice of use the one from anaconda and I can't find the answer anywhere, someone can help me with that?

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nGRu.png)

Comment: You could also delete the corresponding kernelspec entry in the metadata section of your notebook

Answer (score 0):

you can try to remove de kernels inside of the folder changing your user:

rm -r /home/**user**/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/

you can check your kernels as it was post

[remove kernel on jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635310/remove-kernel-on-jupyter-notebook)